# Floating a logo to left using only Css

Tags: html, css

I want to have my nav bar look like this[image]

But so far this is what i've done so far, When I try to float the logo to the left the header background vanishes. I am so confused as to why is this happening?

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
img, fieldset{border: 0; }
img{vertical-align: middle}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight: normal;}

.site-body, .site-header-outer, .site-header, .tag{
  width: 58.7em;
  margin:auto;
}

*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
img, fieldset{border: 0; }
img{vertical-align: middle;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight: normal;}

.site{
  width: 58.7em;
  margin:auto;
}

/*Header*/
.header{
  background-color:#3088f0;
}

.Logo{
  background-color: #f07a30;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>    
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Title</title>

    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div class="site">
      <h1>
        <div class="header">
          <div class="Logo">Vatpaints.tk</div>

        </div>
      </h1>    
      <div class="navigation"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `overflow:hidden;` also consider adding `width: 100%;`. For some browsers the solution without the width does not work.

Another solution to your problem is to clear the float. You can do this by adding an html element as last child of the container in which the elements are floated. Clear the float using inline CSS by adding `style="clear: both;"` as attribute to this last child, or better use a css class.

**Using inline CSS**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="Logo">Vatpaints.tk</div>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

**Using a CSS class**

```
<style>
    .clear{
        clear: left;
        /* clear: right; */
        /* clear: both; */
    }
</style>

<div class="header">
    <div class="Logo">Vatpaints.tk</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding the <div style="clear:left;"></div> solved the issue. Although it is redundant, it is the only one that works. I can't seem to make the other one" <style>..</style>" work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    ...
    overflow: hidden; /* or 'auto'; forces the element to contain the float */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
img,
fieldset {
  border: 0
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: normal
}
.site-body,
.site-header-outer,
.site-header,
.tag {
  width: 58.7em;
  margin: auto;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
img,
fieldset {
  border: 0
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: normal
}
.site {
  width: 58.7em;
  margin: auto;
}
/*Header*/

.header {
  background-color: #3088f0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Logo {
  background-color: #f07a30;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <h1>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="Logo">Vatpaints.tk</div>

        </div>
    </h1> 
  <div class="navigation"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your header has not content and you have not given it a width. The only content it has is the logo which already has it's own bg color.

If you add in some text like how you would like it in the image you posted then you will be able to see the blue bg color for the header. Otherwise as there is no content in it and you have not set a width it will not display as it has nothing to display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a width for your HEADER class div.
You can set the witdth 100% or your arbitrary value, then you can manage the position of your logo.